# Draggable sprites on a wallpaper

Tags: javascript, jquery, matter.js

I'm trying to reproduce something like this: http://carbure.co/.

After inspection the website uses [matter.js](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js), a physics engine. Below is a (failed) code attempt, and I'm having trouble getting it to work given the terrible docs.

Does anyone have any idea how else I can achieve this?

Many thanks

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var w = $(window).innerWidth();
  var h = $(window).innerHeight();

  // Matter.js module aliases
  var Engine = Matter.Engine;
  var World = Matter.World;
  var Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
  var Body = Matter.Body;
  var Constraint = Matter.Constraint;
  var Composite = Matter.Composite;
  var Composites = Matter.Composites;
  var MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

  // create a Matter.js engine
  var engine = Engine.create({
    render: {
      element: document.body,
      options: {
        width: w,
        height: h,
        wireframes: false,
        background: '#fff'
      }
    }
  });

  // add a mouse controlled constraint
  var mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine);
  World.add(engine.world, mouseConstraint);

  var addToWorld = [];

  // create random poly's and a ground
  var ranPolygons = Math.random() * 10 + 5 >> 0;
  var prevPoly;
  for (var i = 0; i < ranPolygons; i++) {
    var polyRadius = Math.random() * 40 + 40 >> 0;
    var polySides = 1;
    var x = Math.random() * (w - polyRadius * 2) + polyRadius >> 0;
    var y = Math.random() * (h / 2 - polyRadius * 2) + polyRadius >> 0;
    var isStatic = Math.random() * 1 < 0.2;

    var poly = Bodies.polygon(x, y, polySides, polyRadius, {
      render: {
        fillStyle: isStatic ? '#0134CB' : makePattern(),
        strokeStyle: isStatic ? 'transparent' : '#0134CB',
        lineWidth: Math.random() * 5 + 2 >> 0
      },
      density: Math.random() * 0.1,
      isStatic: isStatic,
      restitution: Math.random() * 1
    });
    addToWorld.push(poly);

  // add borders
  var border = 5;
  var halfBorder = border / 2;
  var borders = [
    Bodies.rectangle(w / 2, halfBorder, w + border, border, {
      isStatic: true,
      render: {
        fillStyle: 'transparent',
        strokeStyle: 'transparent'
      }
    }),
    Bodies.rectangle(w / 2, h - halfBorder, w + border, border, {
      isStatic: true,
      render: {
        fillStyle: 'transparent',
        strokeStyle: 'transparent'
      }
    }),
    Bodies.rectangle(halfBorder, h / 2, border, h + border, {
      isStatic: true,
      render: {
        fillStyle: 'transparent',
        strokeStyle: 'transparent'
      }
    }),
    Bodies.rectangle(w - halfBorder, h / 2, border, h + border, {
      isStatic: true,
      render: {
        fillStyle: 'transparent',
        strokeStyle: 'transparent'
      }
    }),
  ];
  addToWorld = addToWorld.concat(borders);

  // add all of the bodies to the world
  World.add(engine.world, addToWorld);

  // run the engine
  runner = Engine.run(engine)

  // setTimeout(ranGrav, 2000);
  engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
  engine.world.gravity.x = 0;

  $(engine.render.canvas).css({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100vh'
  })

});
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Do you get errors in the console? Does anything appear? Usually physics engines have an Update() method you must call on some kind of timer...

Comment: It's just still a white screen. I've put that code in the <script/> tag of the website and nothing seems to happen. Any guesses?

Comment: If you press F12, you will get the web developer tools. Go to the Console tab and see if there are any errors. If so, edit question to include them

Comment: `enexpected end of input - index.html:118`. Not sure why? Here is the gist of the only code being used for what I'm trying to do: https://gist.github.com/apswak/346eea77aae240b9cba6f9c16b95d58a

Comment: Usually that means that there is a missing end bracket or something. I.E it is expecting more code but the cide finishes. I dont have time to properly look at the moment (can take a look later) but I would double check all your brackets are matches and things like that

Answer (score 1):

I got your code running. It had a  number of issues. First and foremost, the missing bracket belonged to the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ranPolygons; i++) {
```

Besides that I also had to run the renderer:

```
Render.run(render);
```

And I got rid of this bit, because it was unnecessary and was throwing a warning:

```
$(engine.render.canvas).css({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100vh'
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jx3vn7da/